# HostScript propery returns NULL in XBAP application

Tags: wpf, cross-domain, xbap

We have been using XBAP in our application. For communication between javascript file and XBAP application we are using BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript. When XBAP and parent (.aspx) application are hosted on same server then it is working fine. But when XBAP is on different server and parent site is on another server (cross-domain) then I am getting 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference' error. because I am getting hostScript is NULL. Any solution for this ??

Answer (score 0):

(Mine is not even working locally)

I saw the below on MS documentation. 
(Unfortunately like a lot of MS documentation it is badly written)

The HostScript property **returns null if the frame is navigated to from a cross-domain** location.

This feature can be turned off for Internet Explorer by setting the ScriptInteropDisallow registry value. For more information, see Security (WPF).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.browserinterophelper.hostscript?view=netframework-4.8